# Can anyone give an example of a generic type for dynamically growing chained hashtables?

Tags: c#, hash, hashtable, generic-collections

What's the best way to implement a chained hashtable in C#? For example, the class would be declared like this:

```
     DynamicHashtable<Tkey, Tvalue> 
      {
         ....methods 
      }
```

Where Tkey is the type of the key stored in the table, and TValue is the type of the values associated with the keys. Thus, a hashtable whose keys are strings and whose associated values are integers would be

```
     DynamicHashtable<string, int>
```

Comment: the .NET framework already comes with a data structure that implements chaining as its method for collision resolution: The Dictionary<T, T>. And it is strongly typed with generics for key and value. Does this not already meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hashtable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

If you wish to see details of implementation Hashtable you can review Source Code [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/hashtable.cs,10fefb6e0ae510dd).

Comment: IIRC, .NET hashtables use rehashing, that is propagating to alternative hash functions until no collision is detected.